# jQuery methods, order of optional arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just played around a bit with the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

> .animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )

I know that I dont have to pass all the arguments to a function in javascript. But what I would like to know is how jquery figures out that `function(){ }` refers to the callback function, which is actually the 4:th parameter, instead of the easing string (which is the 3:rd)?

```
$('div').animate({ height: '10px' }, 100, function(){ });
```

Comment: This kind of thing is normally implemented by checking the type of the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are simply tests to check the type :

From [the source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) (`animate` calls `speed`) :

```
jQuery.speed = function( speed, easing, fn ) {
    var opt = speed && typeof speed === "object" ? jQuery.extend( {}, speed ) : {
        complete: fn || !fn && easing ||
            jQuery.isFunction( speed ) && speed,
        duration: speed,
        easing: fn && easing || easing && !jQuery.isFunction( easing ) && easing
    };

...

isFunction: function( obj ) {
        return jQuery.type(obj) === "function";
    },

...

type: function( obj ) {
        return obj == null ?
            String( obj ) :
            class2type[ core_toString.call(obj) ] || "object";
    },

...

core_toString = Object.prototype.toString

...

jQuery.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object".split(" "), function(i, name) {
    class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
});
```

So basically it checks that `Object.prototype.toString.call(fn)` is `"[object Function]"`.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery looks at the **type** of the parameter to find that out, the *easing* parameter is of type **string**, while the *complete* parameter is of type **function**.

See the api for [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) fo find out the types of each parameter.

Example:

```
function test(first, second, third) {
   if (typeof third == 'string') {
       //third is the easing function
   } else if (typeof third == 'function') {
       //third is the callback function
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the *typeof* of argument and *arguments.length*.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter's type could be checked.

Like:

```
if (typeof easing == 'function') {
  complete= easing;
  easing = 'some default value'; 
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be by using typeof() to see if the param is a function, but if you really want to know, check out their source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Answer (score 0):

probably:

```
function test(){};
typeof test // 'function'
```